# Проверка существования объекта класса

Tags: c#

Допустим есть гипотетический класс Class с полями feature1 и feature2.

Где-то в коде создается экземпляр данного класса

```
Class thatclass = new Class(1, 2);
```

Есть ли в C# способ проверки существования именно данного экземпляра с полями  1 и 2? То есть некий метод, которому на вход  подается 1 и 2 и он возвращает true, а если подать другие значения, false?

Comment: Зачем такое может понадобиться?

Comment: Лично у меня вопрос возник, когда мне понадобилось проверить существование вершин графа чтобы заполнить относительно них таблицу смежности. Вершины представляются как экземпляры класса (Vertex v1 = new Vertex(int number, Vertex v, Graph graph)) и нужно как то программе понять, есть такая вершина или нет. Такой вот костыль :)

Comment: Тьфу, блин... Я-то думал, что вам нужен сферический конь в вакууме, что вы хотите определять наличие заранее неизвестного класса в куче CLR, наподобие https://stackoverflow.com/q/2934392/5045688

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально такой возможности нет.
Но никто не запрещает вам сделать свой вариант решения.
Создаем статичный класс и называем его, например, Classes.
Описываем его примерно так:

```
static class Classes
{
    private static List<Class> classes = new List<Class>();

    public static void Add(Class @class)
    {
        classes.Add(@class);
    }

    public static bool Contains(int x, int y)
    {
        return classes.Any(c => c.X == x && c.Y == y);
    }
}
```

Где Class -

```
class Class
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Class(int x, int y)
    {
        Classes.Add(this);

        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

И пробуем проверить существование нужных нам экземпляров:

```
Class class1 = new Class(1, 2);
Class class2 = new Class(2, 3);

Console.WriteLine(Classes.Contains(5, 10)); //FALSE
Console.WriteLine(Classes.Contains(2, 3)); //TRUE
```

Comment: @return Спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Есть, но зачем? Ну да ладно.

```
Dictionary<SomeState, SomeClass> objs;

public bool TryGet(int a, double b, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out SomeClass obj) => objs.TryGetValue(new SomeState(a, b), out obj));

struct SomeState : IEquitable<SomeState> // !!!ВАЖНО!!!
{
    internal int A;
    internal double B;

    // ...
}
```

Ну или так:

```
Dictionary<SomeState, SomeClass> objs;
[ThreadStatic]
SomeState state = new SomeState();

public bool TryGet(/*...*/)
{
    state.A = a;
    state.B = b;

    return objs.TryGetValue(state, out obj);
}

class SomeState : IEquitable<SomeState>
{
    // ...
}
```

Тут мы не копируем потенциально большое (в плане размера) состояние при передаче в `Equals(SomeState, SomeState)`, а используем mutable объект.